# snakemake understand yaml interpretation on alignment command

Tags: snakemake

I have this rule on snakemake file. When I launch the input file are populated from all the input present on my  yaml file. I expect to populate one units key for each process of bwa.
Here you have the rules and Yaml file (not complete) and the  dry run results.

```
rule bwa_mem:
    input:
        dt=expand("trim/{sample}/",sample=config['units']),
        forward_paired=expand("trim/{sample}/{sample}_forward_paired.fq.gz",sample=config['units']),
        reverse_paired=expand("trim/{sample}/{sample}_reverse_paired.fq.gz",sample=config['units']),
        forward_unpaired=expand("trim/{sample}/{sample}_forward_unpaired.fq.gz",sample=config['units']),
        reverse_unpaired=expand("trim/{sample}/{sample}_reverse_unpaired.fq.gz",sample=config['units']),

    output:
        temp("mapped_reads/sam/{unit}.sam")
    params:
        genome= config["reference"]['genome_fasta']
    log:
        "mapped_reads/log/{unit}_bwa_mem.log"
    benchmark:
        "benchmarks/bwa/mem/{unit}.txt"
    threads: 8
    shell:
        '/illumina/software/PROG2/bwa-0.7.15/bwa mem '\
                '-t {threads} {params.genome}  {input.forward_paired} {input.reverse_paired} {input.forward_unpaired} {input.reverse_unpaired} 2> {log} > {output}'
```

And this yaml file configuration:

```
  'samples':
  '432':
  - '432_L001'
  - '432_L002'
  '433':
  - '433_L002'
  - '433_L001'
  '434':
  - '434_L001'
  - '434_L002'
  '435':
  - '435_L002'
  - '435_L001'
....
'units':
  '432_L001':
  - '/illumina/runs/FASTQ/RAW/432_CGATGT_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz'
  - '/illumina/runs/FASTQ/RAW/432_CGATGT_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz'
  '432_L002':
  - '/illumina/runs/FASTQ/RAW/432_CGATGT_L002_R1_001.fastq.gz'
  - '/illumina/runs/FASTQ/RAW/432_CGATGT_L002_R2_001.fastq.gz'
  '433_L001':
  - '/illumina/runs/FASTQ/RAW/433_CAGATC_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz'
  - '/illumina/runs/FASTQ/RAW/433_CAGATC_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz'
  '433_L002':
  - '/illumina/runs/FASTQ/RAW/433_CAGATC_L002_R1_001.fastq.gz'
  - '/illumina/runs/FASTQ/RAW/433_CAGATC_L002_R2_001.fastq.gz'
  '434_L001':
  - '/illumina/runs/FASTQ/RAW/434_GTGAAA_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz'
  - '/illumina/runs/FASTQ/RAW/434_GTGAAA_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz'
  '434_L002':
  - '/illumina/runs/FASTQ/RAW/434_GTGAAA_L002_R1_001.fastq.gz'
  - '/illumina/runs/FASTQ/RAW/434_GTGAAA_L002_R2_001.fastq.gz'
  '435_L001':
  - '/illumina/runs/FASTQ/RAW/435_ACAGTG_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz'
  - '/illumina/runs/FASTQ/RAW/435_ACAGTG_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz'
```

when I try to run he bwa command gave this results

```
rule bwa_mem:
    input: trim/432_L001/432_L001_reverse_unpaired.fq.gz, trim/432_L002/4
32_L002_reverse_unpaired.fq.gz, trim/433_L001/433_L001_reverse_unpaired.f
q.gz, trim/433_L002/433_L002_reverse_unpaired.fq.gz, trim/434_L001/434_L0
01_reverse_unpaired.fq.gz, trim/434_L002/434_L002_reverse_unpaired.fq.gz,
 trim/435_L001/435_L001_reverse_unpaired.fq.gz, trim/435_L002/435_L002_re
verse_unpaired.fq.gz, trim/436_L001/436_L001_reverse_unpaired.fq.gz, trim
/436_L002/436_L002_reverse_unpaired.fq.gz, trim/437_L001/437_L001_reverse
_unpaired.fq.gz, trim/437_L002/437_L002_reverse_unpaired.fq.gz, trim/438_
L003/438_L003_reverse_unpaired.fq.gz, trim/438_L004/438_L004_reverse_unpa
ired.fq.gz,  trim/lane1_L001/lane1_L
001_reverse_paired.fq.gz, trim/lane2_L002/lane2_L002_reverse_paired.fq.gz
, trim/lane8_L008/
    output: mapped_reads/sam/441_L004.sam
    log: mapped_reads/log/441_L004_bwa_mem.log
    jobid: 208
    benchmark: benchmarks/bwa/mem/441_L004.txt
    wildcards: unit=441_L004
```

For any element on units report all the input files... Where I made the mistake?

Comment: bwa should be using wildcards, instead of evaluating {samples}. The evaluation of {samples} should be done in your "all" rule, which I do not see here. Also, consider the tertiary nesting of your samples and units. The second level of samples, equates to the first level of units. I think this can be combined to simply the expansion pattern. Current system requires the check sample[X][Y] == units[X], with only 1 form of referencing, this would no longer be needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, what you do here is that you define all these files  as input files for the rule, via the expand function. In other words, you perform an aggregation here. What you really want here is to have only the set of input files for the specific sample. You achieve that by simply not using the expand function for the input files. There is no reason to use it here.

I strongly suggest to go through the **entire** official Snakemake tutorial, which also covers exactly this kind of question: http://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/tutorial.html

Comment: I would add this advice: Use `expand` as late as possible in your workflow. In practice, most `expand` tend to be in the `all` top rule in the workflows I've written so far. Your mileage may vary.